# How can I display a BusyIndicator during printing in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I want to display a BusyIndicator during printing.  If I turn on my BusyIndicator in the BeginPrint event and turn it off in the EndPrint event, it never appears (BusyIndicator.DisplayAfter is set to 0).  I assume this is because the actual printing is taking place on a different thread.  So if I turn it on before actually calling PrintDocument.Print, the BusyIndicator does show, but of course that's not what I want (the BusyIndicator appears when the user is just selecting his/her printer before actual printing takes place).

I tried creating a property of my user control implemented as a DependencyProperty that BusyIndicator.IsBusy is bound to and setting that property's value true/false in the BeginPrint and EndPrint events.  I tested the binding to this property by setting it true outside of printing, and it works.  But still, when I set that property in the print events, nothing.

I can't do any of the work in the BeginPrint or EndPrint events in a BackgroundWorker either.

How the heck can I turn on my BusyIndicator?

Comment: When you see "BeginX" you can safely assume its an async process.  You can add your own waithandle and look for an event that signals completion.  Haven't done this is silverlight, but looking forward to seeing a final solution.

Comment: Not sure if this works for you, but I was curious and gave it a try. I launch some printing with a Button.Click event. In that event I turned on the BusyIndicator, then turn it off in PrintDocument.EndPrint.

Comment: Have a look at the same question in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843499/silverlight-printing-busy-progress-bar

Answer (score 0):

Hack from Russia ))) I've done it this way: https://cid-99a78e3907425ccf.office.live.com/self.aspx/Sources/PrintDataGrid.RAR . Here I'am printing my DataGrid with showing busyindicator.

Comment: Don't start your posts with 'HACK'